# Split string by special characters '*' in batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, split

I need to delete the substring after *. with a batch file

```
Example : 
The value of string is : TEST_SINISTRE*.csv

rem My code : 
SET mystring="TEST_SINISTRE*.csv"

rem Do the split
SET ext_test=%mystring:*.="& rem %"
SET ext_test=%ext_test%

rem what i get
echo %ext_test% ===> "& rem csv"

rem What i want to see
===> TEST_SINISTRE
```

Can you help me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, and only if, the `*.` pattern can only occur once in the string, and the part after `*.` is not contained in the part before `*.`, the following could be used:

```
rem this is the original string containing one `*.`:
set "STRING=TEST_SINISTRE*.csv"

rem now get everything after `*.`:
rem   (if `*` is the first character in substring substitution, it means everything up to
rem   and including the search string is to be replaced, by nothing here in this case)
set "SUBSTR=%STRING:**.=%"
rem get everything before `*.`, including the `*`:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SUBSTL=!STRING:.%SUBSTR%=!"
rem truncate the `*` from the string:
endlocal & set "SUBSTL=%SUBSTL:~,-1%"
```

Since the substitution syntax for variable expansion is used, this is done in a case-insensitive manner.

To make it more secure, you could append something that will most probably never occur to your original string temporarily and remove it afterwards. To accomplish this, replace the `set` command line between the `setlocal`/`endlocal` block with the following (using appendix `###` here for instance):

```
set "STRING=!STRING!###"
set "SUBSTL=!STRING:.%SUBSTR%###=!"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*` character is a wildcard in batch variable substring substitution.  When you do `*.=something` in an inline substitution, you're really saying "replace everything up to and including the dot".  You should use a `for /F` loop so you can specify the asterisk as a delimiter.

```js
set "str=TEST_SINISTRE*.csv"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=*" %%I in ("%str%") do set "ext_test=%%I%%J"

echo %ext_test%
```

I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is, but here's a hacksy possible alternative.  You could actually create a file called TEST_SINISTRE.csv and then capture the filename into a variable as a wildcard match.

```js
set "str=TEST_SINISTRE*.csv"
type NUL > TEST_SINSTRE.CSV

for %%I in (%str%) do set "ext_test=%%I"

echo %ext_test%
```

I'm sure that's not exactly you have in mind, but it does demonstrate that maybe you don't need to strip the asterisk if you are going to be performing filename matching.